# Flash message modal not displaying after Flask flash and redirection

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am facing an issue with a flash message modal not displaying after executing the flash function and then redirecting to a specific section on my Flask web application. Here is the relevant code:

Flask route:

```
@routes.route('/request_order', methods=['POST'])
def request_order():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        email = request.form.get('email')

        # Perform validation on username and email
        if not username or not email:
            return "Bad email.", 400

        # Generate a verification token and get  payment token
        verification_token = secrets.token_urlsafe(32)
        payment_token = current_app.config['TOKEN']
        # Call the payment_form of the payment provider
        redirected_url = pm.get_payment_form(token=payment_token,
                                         
        redirect_url='...',sum_pay=..., label=verification_token)
        # Send verification email
        msg = Message('...', sender='.....', recipients=[email])
        msg.body = (f"... {redirected_url}")
        from app_captain import mail
        mail.send(msg)

        flash('Email sen', 'success')

        # Redirect to the Ukrainian page
        return redirect(url_for('.index', lang='ua') + '#sneak_peek_section')
```

HTML template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ua">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>....</title>
  <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick- 
    carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick- 
    carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
    family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
    awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" nonce="{{ nonce }}">

  <!-- Add Google Fonts links to import the recommended fonts -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Introduction Section -->

  </section>

  <!-- Modal Order Request -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="orderModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="orderModalLabel">Запрос на получение книги</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <form action="/request_order" method="post">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="username">Ваше имя:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Ваш email:</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Получить ссылку на почту <br/>для оплаты книги</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- Modal for Flash Messages -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="flashMessageModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="flashMessageModalLabel">Сообщение</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Закрити">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <!-- Display the flash message content -->
          {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %} {% if messages %}
          <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          {% endif %} {% endwith %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <input type="hidden" id="flashMessageFlag" value="{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}{% if messages %}1{% else %}0{% endif %}{% endwith %}">
  <!-- Add Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256- 
   2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='execute.js') }}" nonce="{{ nonce }}" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript (execute.js):

```js
    // Initialize a flag to track the availability of flashed messages
    let flashMessageFlag = 0;

    function showFlashMessageModal() {
        const modal = document.getElementById('flashMessageModal');
        if (modal) {
            modal.style.cssText = 'display: block;';  // Use cssText to set styles with the nonce
            modal.setAttribute('nonce', document.querySelector('style').nonce);
        }
    }

    // Function to hide the flash message modal
    function hideFlashMessageModal() {
        const modal = document.getElementById('flashMessageModal');
        if (modal) {
            modal.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    // Function to determine whether to show or hide the modal based on the flag
    function toggleFlashMessageModal(flag) {
      if (flag === 1) {
        showFlashMessageModal();
      } else {
        hideFlashMessageModal();
      }
    }

    // Function to check for flashed messages and set the flag
    function checkFlashMessages() {
      // Show or hide the modal based on the flag
      toggleFlashMessageModal(flashMessageFlag);
    }

    // Call the function to check for flashed messages initially
    checkFlashMessages();

    // Periodically check for flashed messages and update the flag
    setInterval(checkFlashMessages, 1000); // Adjust the interval as needed

    // Automatically close the flash message modal after 15 seconds (15000 milliseconds)
    setTimeout(function() {
        hideFlashMessageModal();
    }, 15000);
    //-------------------------------------------------------

    // Initialize the Slick carousel using vanilla JavaScript
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      const slickCarousels = document.querySelectorAll('.slick-carousel');

      slickCarousels.forEach(function (carousel) {
        new Slick(carousel, {
          dots: true,
          infinite: true,
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        });
      });
    });


    // To control the sneak peeks carousel -->
    const sneakContainer = document.querySelector('.sneak-container');
    const sneaks = document.querySelectorAll('.sneak');
    const nextButton = document.getElementById('next-btn');
    const prevButton = document.getElementById('prev-btn');
    const sneakWidth = sneaks[0].offsetWidth;
    let currentIndex = 0;

     function showSneak(index) {
      const offset = -index * sneakWidth;
      sneakContainer.style.transform = `translateX(${offset}px)`;
    }

    function nextSneak() {
      currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % sneaks.length;
      showSneak(currentIndex);
    }

    function prevSneak() {
      currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + sneaks.length) % sneaks.length;
      showSneak(currentIndex);
    }

    // Show the initial sneak (the first one)
    showSneak(currentIndex);

    // Add event handlers for next and previous buttons
    nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextSneak);
    prevButton.addEventListener('click', prevSneak);

    // Get the scroll-container element
    const carouselContainer = document.getElementById('carouselContainer');

    // Variable to keep track of the scrolling direction
    let scrollDirection = 0;
    let scrollInterval;

    // Function to start scrolling the carousel
    function startScrolling() {
      scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
        carouselContainer.scrollLeft += 1; // Adjust the scrolling speed as needed

        // Check if the carousel has reached the end
        if (carouselContainer.scrollLeft >= carouselContainer.scrollWidth - carouselContainer.clientWidth) {
          // Reset the scroll position to the start of the carousel
          carouselContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
        }
      }, 10); // Adjust the scrolling speed as needed
    }

    // Function to stop scrolling the carousel
    function stopScrolling() {
      clearInterval(scrollInterval);
    }


    // Add a mouseover event listener to the container to enable horizontal scrolling
    carouselContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
      // Set the scroll direction to 0 when the mouse is over the carousel
      scrollDirection = 0;
      // Start scrolling the carousel
      startScrolling();
    });


    // Add a mouseout event listener to stop scrolling when the mouse leaves the carousel
    carouselContainer.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
      // Stop scrolling the carousel
      stopScrolling();
    });


    // Add a wheel event listener to the container to handle mouse wheel scrolling
    carouselContainer.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
      // Prevent the default vertical scrolling behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Determine the scrolling direction based on the wheel delta
      scrollDirection += event.deltaY;

      // Scroll left if the wheel delta is positive (scrolling forward)
      if (scrollDirection > 0) {
        carouselContainer.scrollLeft += 50; // Adjust the scrolling speed as needed
      }
      // Scroll right if the wheel delta is negative (scrolling backward)
      else {
        carouselContainer.scrollLeft -= 50; // Adjust the scrolling speed as needed
      }

      // Check if the carousel has reached the end
      if (carouselContainer.scrollLeft >= carouselContainer.scrollWidth - carouselContainer.clientWidth) {
        // Reset the scroll position to the start of the carousel
        carouselContainer.scrollLeft = 0;
      }

      // Check if the carousel has reached the start
      if (carouselContainer.scrollLeft <= 0) {
        // Reset the scroll position to the end of the carousel
        carouselContainer.scrollLeft = carouselContainer.scrollWidth - carouselContainer.clientWidth;
      }
    });


    //  To handle the buying button link -->
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      const preOrderButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".pre-order-button");
      preOrderButtons.forEach(function(button) {
        button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          window.location.href = "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0CDM8BCQW";
        });
      });
    });


    // To handle the "Contribute Now" button link -->
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      const contributeButton = document.querySelector(".contribute-button");
      contributeButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href = "https://fundrazr.com//helge_eirinn";
      });
    });

    // Get the orderModal element
    const orderModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('orderModal'));

    // Add click event listener to the button
    document.getElementById('openOrderModalBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
      // Show the modal
      orderModal.show();
    });
```

The problem is that after return from route '/request_order' is done, the flash message is not displaying in the modal when redirected to the index route. The modal is not visible.
There are no error messages in the console after redirect.
But I have such issue when the index.html is loaded in the first time.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop')
> at On._initializeBackDrop (modal.js:158:39)
> at new On (modal.js:69:27)
> at execute.js:187:24 (const orderModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('orderModal'));)

Any insights into why the flash message modal is not appearing after the redirect would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!